# Multiple if else statement in repeater for visible

Tags: c#, if-statement, repeater

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnlike" runat="server" src="images/sheart1.png" 
Visible='<%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("likeunlike")) == 1 ? true :  false%>'/>

Select likeunlike from tbllike.
```

I am using select statement to select and bind but sometimes it will return no rows.

```
 Visible='<%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("likeunlike")) == 1 || Eval("likeunlike") 
 == DBNull.Value ? true :  false%>'.
```

I wanna check if no row return will be visible but still cannot. Can someone help?

Comment: Why can you not? What goes wrong? What has the content of your question got to do with the title? Have you read [ask]?

Comment: there is no display of the button even through it returns no row

Comment: How did you go reading [ask]?

Answer (score 0):

maybe add another check to make sure it isn't null. I don't know the format you are working with, but maybe something like this :-

```
!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("likeunlike")) && Convert.ToInt32(Eval("likeunlike")) == 1 ? true :  false
```